# How Do You Update/Refresh Requests In Postman After Importing WSDL

Tags: soap, collections, postman, wsdl, soapui

After importing WSDL into a new collection in Postman ({Collection} > Import > Link > Url), is there not a way to update or refresh the Collection's requests when the API is modified?

1. I've tried re-importing it, but it just creates a new collection.
2. If I don't check "[ ] Generate collection from imported APIs", it just creates a blank API with no requests.

In SoapUI, you have the option of updating/refreshing all of your requests/responses because their signatures change over time. This seems like a pretty big omission if there's no way to refresh. I would lose all of my collection's tests and variables if I had to create a new set each time something changed.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Brent